# Can I run 2 gunicorn doing different tasks to one and other on one server?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, scheduled-tasks, gunicorn

Currently I am running with 1 worker. I want to increase my number of workers. But now if I increase the number of workers my background services will also increase. Leads to duplicate data.

For example:

I have an email inbox scanning service that runs on repeat every minute. If there is new email will generate data in mongoDB. So if run with 1 worker it's fine. but when increase to 3 workers it will loop, resulting in 1 email coming it will scan 3 times and generate 3 data on mongoDB.

My idea would be to separate the services that run repeatedly for a period of time that will run gunicorn with 1 worker. The remaining Gunicorn will run with 3 workers to increase API processing performance.

According to the manual: recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers to start off with.

My computer has 4 CPUs. So I will follow the formula (2 * core) + 1. We get (2 * 4) + 1 = 9 is the number of workers that are suitable for the system.

*- I use 8 workers to run the first Gunicorn to process the API with port **8000**:*

**gunicorn --workers=8 --bind x.x.x.x:8000 xxxproject.wsgi:application**

*- I use 1 worker left to run inbox scanning service with port **8001**:*

**gunicorn --workers=1 --bind x.x.x.x:8001 xxxproject.wsgi:application**

**Those of you who have experience in this field please give me advice, is my method correct and the pros and cons if any? Thank you very much !!!!**

Comment: If this is a background service you dont want it using all your resources so maybe go with a lower number of workers, ideally you want a method of assigning workers to each email to prevent duplicate work so maybe you need a wrapper service that spawns your workers and assigns emails for each to scan.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. How will we do it? I am new in this field !

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason you're running gunicorn I would recommend just creating a python service script that runs your tasks using https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html and then sleeps. Splitting your services into two isn't likely to improve performance since you're constrained by scanning time. This has useful information on using systemd https://github.com/torfsen/python-systemd-tutorial.